# How to modify groupby.cumcount() to get the count and the occurrence in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to find the occurrence and add the occurrence if it is repeating. I tried `groupby.cumcount` but it doesn't increment when a new value is there. I need the output as mentioned below if the description is confusing.

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1200 | 1 |
| 1 | 1300 | 2 |
| 2 | 1400 | 3 |
| 3 | 1400 | 3 |
| 4 | 1400 | 3 |
| 5 | 1300 | 2 |
| 6 | 1500 | 4 |
| 7 | 1500 | 4 |

Comment: Please don't post images / links to images. Add code as text to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`Groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html). It numbers each group from 0 to `groups-1`. You can add 1 to the resulting Series, so that the numbering starts at 1

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').ngroup().add(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   col1
0  1200
1  1300
2  1400
3  1400
4  1400
5  1300
6  1500
7  1500

>>> df.groupby('col1').ngroup()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    3
7    3
dtype: int64

>>> df.groupby('col1').ngroup().add(1)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    2
6    4
7    4
dtype: int64
```